# Stimulus JS script to calculate a total

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

[So here in the black square I get the sum of the 'Precio' (price) * the 'Orden' (quantity) and then I want to get the sum of everything in the black square where the red square is which is the 'Total'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wbYz.png)

- This is my current script:

  ```
    <script>
  (() => {
    const application = Stimulus.Application.start()

    const calculationController = class extends Stimulus.Controller {
      static targets = [ "precio", "cantidad", "output" ]

      calculate() {
        this.outputTarget.textContent = this.precioTarget.innerHTML * this.cantidadTarget.value
      }  
    }

    application.register("calculation", calculationController)
  })()
  ```

  (() => {
        const application = Stimulus.Application.start()

  ```
    const totalController = class extends Stimulus.Controller {
      static targets = [ "valor", "total" ]

      total() {
        this.totalTarget.textContent = this.valorTarget.value += this.totalTarget.value
      }
    }

    application.register("total", totalController)
  })()
  ```
- And this is what I have in my _form.html.erb, just the part where I use anything Stimulus wise

  ```
    <% @client.catalog.products.each do |product| %>
    <tr data-controller="calculation">
      <td><%= product.nombre %></td>
      <td data-target="calculation.precio"><%= product.precio %></td>
      <td><input data-action="change->calculation#calculate" data-target="calculation.cantidad" type="number" class="orden-field"></td>
      <td><span data-action="change->total#total" data-target="total.valor calculation.output">
      </span></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>IVA:</td>
      <td><span data-target="calculation.output"></span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><%= form.label :total, "Total:", class: "orden-field" %></td>
      <td><!--<%= form.text_field :total, class: "orden-field" 
      %>--><span data-target="total.total"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  ```
- Any suggestions on how I can successfully get the total sum from the 3 elements?

Comment: Why not just write a method that you can call to return the sum?

Comment: its because that last 'Valor' column is not a column in the table, wouldn't it need to be a column so that I can do a method? if not how would I do it exactly? I'm not too familiar with methods.

Comment: I mean you could just grab all the values using javascript and then add them up and put it in that field.  There are a bunch of different ways you could acahieve this, what have you tried so far?

Comment: only stimulus i've been at it for a while, maybe I'm missing something that's why I came up here to come up with an easier way to do it:(